# Deterministic way of getting WeekEnding (Sun) for given date column (for use in computed column)

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, calculated-columns

Take the following SQL table (fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/578bc/1/0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_DateExample] (
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [BookingDate] [DATE] NOT NULL ,
    [WeekEnding] AS ( DATEADD(DAY, ( 6 ) - ( ( DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [BookingDate]) + @@datefirst ) - ( 2 ) ) % ( 7 ), [BookingDate]) ) ,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_DateExample] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID] ASC )
)
```

Note its use of a computed column, this computed column calculates the WeekEnding (Sunday) date for whatever date is in the BookingDate column regardless of the `@@datefirst` environmental variable - this column MUST contain Sundays only.

This works great in production, but we need to apply an index to this computed column, and to do that we need to make it a persisted computed column, unfortunately our use of `@@datefirst` makes it non-deterministic and prevents persistence & indexing.

How can we re-create this columns data (i.e. the WeekEnding (Sunday) for whatever date is in the BookingDate column) but make it deterministic & ready for indexing?

PS: I'd rather avoid triggers if at all possible as the production table is already an extremely complex, high traffic table with millions of rows & several triggers already in place.

**Edit: Final Code Used:**

```
DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATE, '01/01/1990', 103), BookingDate) % 7, BookingDate)
```

Comment: I've found the best solution for this is to create a calendar table with the attributes for each date pre-computed, since they never change.  Easy to index, and everything is a quick lookup instead of a calculation.

Comment: Hi dbugger, the need for this index has come from a requirement to group 100’s of millions of rows by Week in addition to using the WeekEnding in the WHERE clause, we already have calendar tables but joining the millions of dates proved to perform poorly, even with clustered index on calendar table and non-clustered on BookingDate column. A persisted on-page computed index should perform better and make for tidier tsql :)

Comment: Used this solution just fine on 70 years worth of dates and over a billion rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A kind of ugly but solid solution would be, to rely on a fixed date value, and then use the date difference modulo 7 as an alternative to the `DATEPART` function:

```
DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [BookingDate])  -- with @@datefirst = 1
```

is equivalent to:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATETIME,'1990-01-01',120), [BookingDate]) % 7 + 1  -- because 1990-01-01 is a monday
```

So use something like the following. **Note:** I haven't tested this yet, so you should probably fiddle with the offset values in the `[WeekEnding]` calculation, until you get it right:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_DateExample] (
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [BookingDate] [DATE] NOT NULL ,
    [WeekEnding] AS ( DATEADD(DAY, ( 6 ) - (DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATETIME,'1990-01-01 00:00:00.000',120), [BookingDate]) % 7), [BookingDate]) ) ,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_DateExample] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID] ASC )
)
```

Also, if you have `BookingDate` values that lie before 1990-01-01, you might run into issues where the DATEDIFF returns a negative value. In that case, adjust the fixed date value to make sure it lies before any of your `BookingDate` values.

Comment: Sorry Dan, but this wont work either as DATEDIFF() isn't Deterministic

Comment: Not to worry. The calculation can just as easily be made by simple subtraction: `CAST([BookingDate] AS DATETIME) - `1990-01-01'`. This should be deterministic. Updated my answer.

Comment: @HeavenCore, `DATEDIFF` is deterministic (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx). `CAST` is not deterministic for `DATETIME`. In this case, just the `CONVERT` of the 1990-01-01 `DATETIME` was missing to make it deterministic.

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez: Nicely spotted. So we can still use `DATEDIFF` as long as we `CONVERT` '1990-01-01' to `DATETIME` beforehand?

Comment: Yes @Dan, there is no problem using DATEDIFF. The convert is needed because the implicit conversion of the date string is non-deterministic. I had the same issue a couple of days ago ;)